# Accessing View in awakeFromNib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have been trying to set a UIImageView background color (see below) in awakeFromNib

```
[imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
```

When it did not work, I realised that its probably because the view has not loaded yet and I should move the color change to viewDidLoad.

Can I just verify that I have this right?

gary

**EDIT_002:**

I have just started a fresh project to check this from a clean start. I setup the view the same as I always do. The results are that the controls are indeed set to (null) in the awakeFromNib. Here is what I have:

CODE:

```
@interface iPhone_TEST_AwakeFromNibViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *myLabel;
    UIImageView *myView;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *myView;
@end
```

.

```
@synthesize myLabel;
@synthesize myView;

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib ...");
    NSLog(@"myLabel: %@", [myLabel class]);
    NSLog(@"myView : %@", [myView class]);
    //[myLabel setText:@"AWAKE"];
    [super awakeFromNib];

}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad ...");
    NSLog(@"myLabel: %@", [myLabel class]);
    NSLog(@"myView : %@", [myView class]);
    //[myLabel setText:@"VIEW"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
awakeFromNib ...
myLabel: (null)
myView : (null)
viewDidLoad ...
myLabel: UILabel
myLabel: UIImageView
```

I would be interested to know if this should work, from the docs it looks like it should, but given the way I usually set things up I can't quite understand why it does not in this case.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One more answer :-) It looks like you’re getting this behaviour because the controller loads the views lazily. The view is not loaded immediately, it gets loaded the first time somebody calls the `view` accessor. Therefore at the time you recieve `awakeFromNib` the NIB loading process is done, but *not for the objects inside your views*. See this code:

```
@property(retain) IBOutlet UILabel *foo;
@synthesize foo;

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"#1: %i", !!foo);
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSLog(@"#2: %i", !!foo);
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"#3: %i", !!foo);
}
```

This logs:

```
#1: 0
#2: 0
#3: 1
```

But if you force-load the view:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"#1: %i", !!foo);
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self view]; // forces view load
    NSLog(@"#2: %i", !!foo);
}
```

The log changes into this:

```
#1: 0
#3: 1
#2: 1
```

Comment: Thank you Zoul, thats very interesting. I guess I am just better off using viewDidLoad as forcing the view to load calls it first anyways. I did also read that using awakeFromNib might not be a good idea on the iPhone, but there seems to be mixed opinion on that. Thanks again ...

Comment: If you don't have access to the view, then do a performSelector:withObject:delay call from awakeFromNib. A hack, but effective.

Comment: Just stumbled across this question and answer for the first time - it would've saved me a bunch of trouble if I'd found it earlier! The issue still exists in 2013, and I believe that the behaviour contradicts the documentation - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400547/awakefromnib-outlets-and-storyboards-is-the-documentation-wrong

Comment: Any solution if overriding a UIView? It doesn't have viewDidLoad. Might have to do the performSelector hack.

Comment: I tried the same thing but still getting `nil` for outlets bind with subclass of UIview.

Comment: I checked outlets by placing dispatch_after with duration of 5 sec, but still it shows me `nil`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your call to super needs to be the first line in the awakeFromNib method, otherwise the elements won't be setup yet.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];
  [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
  [testLabel setText:@"Pants ..."];  
}
```

Comment: This is a good guess and `super` should be indeed called first, but it does not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this post is a bit older, but I recently had a similar problem and would like to share its solution with you.

Having subclassed NSTextView, I wanted to display the row colors in alternating orders. To be able to alter the colors from outside, I added two instance vars to my subclass, XNSStripedTableView:

```
@interface XNSStripedTableView : NSTableView {

    NSColor *pColor; // primary color
    NSColor *sColor; // secondary color
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSColor *pColor;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSColor *sColor;

@end
```

Overwriting highlightSelectionInClipRect: does the trick to set the correct color for the respective clipRect.

```
- (void)highlightSelectionInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
```

{

```
float rowHeight = [self rowHeight] + [self intercellSpacing].height;
NSRect visibleRect = [self visibleRect];
NSRect highlightRect;

highlightRect.origin = NSMakePoint(NSMinX(visibleRect), (int)(NSMinY(clipRect)/rowHeight)*rowHeight);
highlightRect.size = NSMakeSize(NSWidth(visibleRect), rowHeight - [self intercellSpacing].height);

while (NSMinY(highlightRect) < NSMaxY(clipRect)) {

    NSRect clippedHighlightRect = NSIntersectionRect(highlightRect, clipRect);
    int row = (int) ((NSMinY(highlightRect)+rowHeight/2.0)/rowHeight);
    NSColor *rowColor = (0 == row % 2) ? sColor : pColor;
    [rowColor set];
    NSRectFill(clippedHighlightRect);
    highlightRect.origin.y += rowHeight;
}

[super highlightSelectionInClipRect: clipRect];
```

}

The only problem now is, where to set the initial values for pColor and sColor? I tried awakeFromNib:, but this would cause the debugger to come up with an error. So I dug into the problem with NSLog: and found an easy but viable solution: setting the initial values in **viewWillDraw:**. As the objects are not created calling the method the first time, I had to check for **nil**.

```
- (void)viewWillDraw {

if ( pColor == nil ) 
    pColor = [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:0.33 green:0.33 blue:0 alpha:1] retain];

if ( sColor == nil ) 
    sColor = [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:0.66 green:0.66 blue:0 alpha:1] retain];
```

}

I do think this solution is quite nice :-) although one could reselect the names of pColor and sColor could be adjusted to be more "human readable".

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure the objects are not `nil`? `NSAssert` or `NSParameterAssert` are your friends:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib {
    NSParameterAssert(imageView);
    NSParameterAssert(testLabel);
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib ...");
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
    [testLabel setText:@"Pants ..."];
    [super awakeFromNib];
}
```

If the objects are really initialized, try to log their address and make sure that the instances that appear in `viewDidLoad` are the same as those in `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"test label #1: %@", testLabel);
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"test label #2: %@", testLabel);
}
```

If the numbers are the same, you can create a category to set a breakpoint on `setBackgroundColor` and peek in the stack trace to see what’s going on:

```
@implementation UIImageView (Patch)
- (void) setBackgroundColor: (UIColor*) whatever {
    NSLog(@"Set a breakpoint here.");
}
@end
```

You can do the same trick using a custom subclass:

```
@interface PeekingView : UIImageView {}
@end

@implementation PeekingView
- (void) setBackgroundColor: (UIColor*) whatever {
    NSLog(@"Set a breakpoint here.");
    [super setBackgroundColor:whatever];
}
@end
```

Now you’ll set your `UIViewObject` to be of class `PeekingView` in the Interface Builder and you’ll know when anybody tries to set the background. This should catch the case where somebody overwrites the background changes after you initialize the view in `awakeFromNib`.

But I presume that the problem will be much more simple, ie. `imageView` is most probably `nil`.

Comment: Hi Zoul, much appreciated, I will go through your suggestions first thing in the morning and let you know how I get on. Your probably right about it being something simple, let me have a better look.

Comment: Hi Zoul, the controls were indeed nil, (See Edit_002 above)

Answer (score -2):

In case you're using a UIView subclass instead of a UIViewController subclass, you can override `loadView` method:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    //IBOutlets are not nil here.
}
```