# Rotate (angle) a UIView, using User Defined Runtime Attributes

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard, cgaffinetransform

Is it possible to rotate a UIView or UIImageView, say 10 or 15 degrees,

actually using User Defined Runtime Attributes?

Or can it only be done in code?

(Note .. I mention "angle" and "by degrees" for the sake of google; it can get mixed-up with the idea of "rotating" for device orientation change.)

---

Alternately, could you perhaps **subclass** UIView in such a way that, a User Defined Runtime Attribute would be exposed, which does just this?  (I'm rusty :/ )

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `layer.transform.rotation.z` key path for `UIView` object.
Value has to be set in radians:

[image]

Result:

[image]

All transformation key paths are presented in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html).

Comment: I confirmed it worked - I checked it with a UILabel. Fantastic!

Comment: Is there a way to do this today? It isn't working for me in Xcode 9.4.1.

Comment: This doesn't update in the xib, but if you run it will render in the app.

Answer (score 4):

In extension to this answer [How to access User Defined Runtime Attribute from the 'sender' object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007542/how-to-access-user-defined-runtime-attribute-from-the-sender-object), you can retrieve the runtime value as an NSNumber in degrees, and then perform the rotation. Trigger the 
`IBAction` in interface builder when you want the rotation to occur.

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)

@interface RTFRotatingView : UIView
@end

@implementation RTFRotatingView

- (IBAction)performRotation:(UIControl *)sender {
    if ([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(keyName)]) {
        NSNumber *degrees = [sender valueForKey:@"keyName"];
        CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(degrees.doubleValue));
        self.transform = rotateTransform;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Max, I'm not totally sure how this solves the problem posed in the question here??

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, you can set the number of degrees i.e. `10` as a value in the user defined runtime attributes for the view in interface builder. From there, by subclassing the `UIView`, you can retrieve the value and perform the rotation.

Comment: Max, what the heck call do you use in a subclass of UIView (so, I remember vaguely it's something like "when unloaded" .. kind of equivalent to "viewDidLoad" in a VC) ... to do that automatically when the view is unboxed from the IB?  cheers...

Comment: Oh yeah .. it's awakeFromNib.  But note the warning from Joe Blow in the comment here ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/6927658/294884  I do not know if you can CGAffineTransformRotate in awakeFromNib .. it may be like animations, which you can't do.

Comment: @JoeBlow give it a try, otherwise run it on a timer to perform the rotation after x seconds. Alternatively see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167734/556479