# UIImageView shadow not working

Tags: ios, uikit

Am not sure where an wrong. I have an UIImageView in Storyboard, which am connecting with an IBOutlet to the code. I want to add a shadow (during runtime) to the UIImageView. And am using this code snippet for that (got this help from a stackoverflow post) :

```
-(void) awakeFromNib { 
    self.imageViewTopBar.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.imageViewTopBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 5);
    self.imageViewTopBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    self.imageViewTopBar.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
        //self.imageViewTopBar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    //self.imageViewTopBar.clipsToBounds = NO;
    self.imageViewTopBar.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}
```

but it simply doesn't work. Any help please? I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

My environment : XCode 4.5.2, iOS 5, iPhone 4

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-viewDidLoad` to do this, check out this post: [Accessing View in awakeFromNib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723042/accessing-view-in-awakefromnib)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it into viewDidLoad.  I assume you've included the quartzcore framework.  I think it would throw compiler error if not...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have checked, in the xib, clipToBounds to YES?

If YES you should uncheck the clipToBounds and reorganize your view hierarchy.

Normally when i have an imageView with a shadow i use this hierarchy

```
(aImageView)   ClipToBounds=YES
     |
     |
   (aView)     Shadow setted here
     |
     |
 (Superview)
```

aView has the same frame size of the aImageView