# IBOutlets are nil in awakeFromNib when using size classes feature

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, xib

There are a lot of similar questions to this, however I coudn't find exactly my issue.

I created xib file where I placed only one `UIView` and linked it to my custom class.
I also added some components like buttons and labels to this view.

Then I instantiate the view like this:

```
NSArray* viewsInNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:name owner:self options:nil];
view = [viewsInNib objectAtIndex:0];
```

And when I'm trying to handle `awakeFromNib`:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // outlets are nil here
}
```

I realize that my outlets are nil.

The interesting point is that if I don't use size classes and go with basic option (wAny/hAny) this way works, all outlets are exist and can be used. However when I change the class to some other like iphone option (wCompact, hAny) and launch the app on iphone device, I see that my components, which was created in custom class size are `nil` in the `awakeFromNib` method, and after some delay they are all set.

It looks like components wich was added in custom size class are not inited in `awakeFromNib`method, what is quite odd.

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this issue!

Comment: The views are not yet initialized in awakeFromNib.  Check out this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723042/accessing-view-in-awakefromnib